# Web Api PushStreamContent Writes a message instead of Streaming pdf or epub files

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I have this method:

```
[HttpGet("GetFile")]
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> getFile([FromQuery] string url)
        {           
            try
            {
                url = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(url);
                var inputStream = await client.GetStreamAsync(url);                                  
                string regex = ".+\\/{2}.+\\/{1}.+(\\.\\w+)\\?*.*";
                var match = Regex.Match(url, regex);
                string ext = null;
                if (match.Success)
                {
                    ext = match.Groups[1].Value.Replace(".", ""); 
                }
                else
                    ext = "octet-stream";
                HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
                response.Content = new PushStreamContent(async (outputStream, content, context) =>
                {                    
                    BinaryWriter responseStreamWriter = new BinaryWriter(outputStream);
                    const int bufferSize = 1 << 10;
                    var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                    while (true)
                    {
                        var bytesRead = await inputStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                        if (bytesRead == 0) break;
                        responseStreamWriter.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    }
                }, $"application/{ext}");
                return response;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
            }
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
        }
```

But instead of streaming the file to client, It gets this line of json:

```
{"version":"1.1","content":{"headers":[{"key":"Content-Type","value":["application/pdf"]}]},"statusCode":200,"reasonPhrase":"OK","headers":[],"trailingHeaders":[],"requestMessage":null,"isSuccessStatusCode":true}
```

How to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try switching to `ActionResult` and return `FileResult` via `Controller.File` method. Something along this lines:

```
[HttpGet("GetFile")]
public async Task<ActionResult> getFile([FromQuery] string url)
{
    url = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(url);
    Stream inputStream = await client.GetStreamAsync(url);
    string regex = ".+\\/{2}.+\\/{1}.+(\\.\\w+)\\?*.*";
    var match = Regex.Match(url, regex);
    string ext = null;
    if (match.Success)
    {
        ext = match.Groups[1].Value.Replace(".", "");
    }
    else
        ext = "octet-stream";

    return File(inputStream, ext);
}
```